# How to check if a particular XML node exists by using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Since the `"<dnsServer>"` or `"<dnsServers>"` tags don't exist I am getting an error. I am trying to check if it is a null but my code is not working. I get the error:

> {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Here is the code:

```
var networkElement = doc.Root
                        .Element("networkAdapters")
                        .Elements("networkAdapter")
                        .First(a => (string)a.Attribute("id") == networkAdapter.networkAdapterId.ToString());

var dnsServers = networkElement.Element("dnsServers")
                               .Elements("dnsServer") == null ? null : networkElement.Element("dnsServers").Elements("dnsServer");
```

and XML sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<server id="454a8a22-8e9e-4023-9a8e-c8a4e0f259b3" productName="Manifest" created="2014-01-16T22:07:28" name="SERVER001">
  <networkAdapters>
    <networkAdapter id="bfcbda99-719c-4b0c-b7b2-b9167350c982" busLocation="0-N2" permanentMacAddress="00144FE5448E" physicalAdapter="True" ipEnabled="False">
      <defaultGateways />
      <ipAddresses />
    </networkAdapter>
    <networkAdapter id="73606723-fd91-40df-96dd-0bff7851cea6" ipEnabled="True">
      <defaultGateways>
        <defaultGateway address="99.15.210.1" index="0" />
      </defaultGateways>
      <ipAddresses>
        <ipAddress address="99.15.210.7" subnetMask="255.255.255.224" index="0" />
      </ipAddresses>
    </networkAdapter>
    <networkAdapter id="6520a041-2cf3-40b1-b123-1eb13f704442" busLocation="0-N3" permanentMacAddress="00144FE5448F" physicalAdapter="True" ipEnabled="False">
      <defaultGateways />
      <ipAddresses />
    </networkAdapter>
  </networkAdapters>
</server>
```

Thank you

Comment: How does your XML looks like?

Comment: just posted. Sometimes we receive file without the <dnsServer> tag which is inside the <networkAdapter>

Comment: well, I need to be able to check if there are any ipAddresses, in other words, to verify if we have the tag <ipAddress>. Same for <dnsServer>. One thing I noticed in this xml file is that I have the tag <ipAddresses> but not <dnsServers>, so I need to find a logic to check if I have any ipAddresses or dnsServers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

```
var servers = networkElement.Element("dnsServers") ?? new XElement("dnsServers");
var dnsServers = servers.Elements("dnsServer");
```

It will create empty `<dnsServers>` when there is non in your document to let your `Elements("dnsServer")` query work without exception.

You can do that as one-liner:

```
var dnsServers = (networkElement.Element("dnsServers") ?? new XElement("dnsServers")).Elements("dnsServer");
```

Comment: It is returning NOT NULL when it should be null since I don't have "dnsServers" in the file. Am I missing something? thanks

Comment: It returns an empty collection when there is not element. But to make things clear: do you need list of `<dnsServer>` elements or just one `<dnsServers>` elements/`null`?

Comment: well, I need to be able to check if there are any ipAddresses, in other words, to verify if we have the tag <ipAddress>. Same for <dnsServer>. One thing I noticed in this xml file is that I have the tag <ipAddresses> but not <dnsServers>, so I need to find a logic to check if I have any ipAddresses or dnsServers. - thanks

Comment: nevermind, what you proposed works just fine, just realized it was an empty collection, sorry....thank you so much